# Vuejs lazyloading router with webpack

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Following this guide:  https://alligator.io/vuejs/lazy-loading-routes/

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const Other = r => require.ensure([], () => r(require('./components/Other.vue')))
const Home = { template: '<div><h2>Home Page</h2></div>'}

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/other', component: Other }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

This outputs the main js file as well as another for the said component. Fairly painless.

Is it however possible to tidy this line up somehow. I tried to wrap the line in a function but this spits out a warning: 
"WARNING in ./src/main.js
13:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"

Here is the abstraction failing to build with webpack...

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import About from './components/About.vue'
import Other from './components/Other.vue'

let lazyLoader = function( path ){
  return r => require.ensure([], () => r(require(path)))
}

const LazyAbstraction  = lazyLoader('./components/LazyLoadMePlease.vue')
const Home = { template: '<div><h2>Home Page</h2></div>'}
const Contact = { template: '<div><h2>Contact Page</h2></div>'}

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/about', component: About },
  { path: '/lazy', component: LazyAbstraction },
  { path: '/contact', component: Contact },
  { path: '/other', component: Other }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: According to ES6, if a variable is being reassigned multiple times , its recommended to use let

Comment: Hmm, changing it to let from const makes no difference :/

Comment: did you try this ? require.ensure([path], () => r(require(path)))

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/215

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `require.ensure`

Try this method `const Foo = () => import('./Foo.vue')` from [LazyLoading Vue](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Webpack will be parsed another js file for each `import()`